# How to make so that page will have no number in latex?

Tags: page-numbering

How to make so that page will have no number in latex? I mean for example if i dont want first page to have number "1" under

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Your text.

\end{document}
```

Just use `\thispagestyle{empty}` for one page without page numbering or `\pagestyle{empty}` for every page without page numbering.

Comment: @NarminaBaghirova ur welcome. If my comment helped, you might want to give me an upvote and the correct sign? If not, you might tell me what misses in my answer? :-)